# Document-Based App with Swift

Tags: core-data, swift, document-based, xcode6

Can someone please tell me how to fix the Apple Template in Xcode 6 for a document-based app with Swift.  I've tried with and without core data(prefer with), with storyboards instead of regular Xibs.  The standard, out of the box template returns a "The [insert document type here] type doesn't map to any NSDocumentClass.  It's pretty frustrating when they release a new language with templates that don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the addition of modules in Xcode 6 and swift, you now have to qualify the document class type.  For example, if my application name is MyApp (and I haven't created any other modules), and my document type is MyDoc, in Document Types the class should be listed as MyApp.MyDoc.

I can't post screenshots of this yet because the NDA, but here are the steps to recreate what I changed:

1. Inside Xcode, click on your application in the explorer pane
2. Select your application under targets
3. Click the *Info* tab on the top toolbar
4. Expand *Document Types*

**Name** - Document Type (your choice)

**Class** - MyApp.MyDoc  <--- Reflects the addition of modules, this won't show up in the dropdown (at least not as of Dev Preview 4)

**Extensions** - mydoc (your choice)

**Icon** - your icon image file

**Identifier** - some unique identifier for the document type, generally use com.companyname.extension

**Role** - editor (your choice)

**Mime Types** - None (if you are using an XML Store you could change this to text/xml)

**Bundled** - false

*Additional Info - I didn't have to add this to the exported UTI's, but I think its best practice to do so*